# How to set page layout break on worksheet using EPPlus

Tags: c#, export-to-excel, epplus

Is there a way to set specify where to break the page using EEPlus? I have the following code that sets the printer properties but haven't found a way to set a break point on a certain column.

```
// Set printer settings
ws.PrinterSettings.PaperSize = ePaperSize.Tabloid;
ws.PrinterSettings.Orientation = eOrientation.Landscape;
ws.PrinterSettings.FitToPage = true;
ws.PrinterSettings.FitToHeight = 1;
ws.PrinterSettings.FooterMargin = .05M;
ws.PrinterSettings.TopMargin = .05M;
ws.PrinterSettings.LeftMargin = .05M;
ws.PrinterSettings.RightMargin = .05M;
```

Edit (this helped solve my problem)

```
ws.Column(30).PageBreak = true;
ws.PrinterSettings.PaperSize = ePaperSize.A3;
ws.PrinterSettings.Orientation = eOrientation.Landscape;
ws.PrinterSettings.Scale = 75;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just need to get reference to the `Row` and/or `Column` objects:

```
ws.Row(20).PageBreak = true;
ws.Column(2).PageBreak = true;
```

But keep in mind that `FitToPage` might suppress these.

Comment: Took a while to figure out. You're right it doesn't work with **FitToPage** set to true but working with **Scale** helped fit the columns onto the broken up pages.